# What is wrong with my function testing for membership in a binary search tree?

Tags: haskell, types, binary-search-tree, membership

Lets say I have the following datatype:

`data BinaryTree a = EmptyTree | Node a (BinaryTree a) (BinaryTree a) deriving (Eq, Ord, Show)`

and the following function

```
  member a EmptyTree = False
  member a (Node x l r)
    | a < x = member a l
    | a > x = member a r
    | a == x = True
```

This function works.

examining the type of `Node`:

```
:t Node
Node :: a -> BinaryTree a -> BinaryTree a -> BinaryTree a
```

However, if the member function is given a signature:
`member :: Node a -> BinaryTree a -> Bool`

(`Node` of type a and `BinaryTree` of type a producing a `Bool`)

it errors out with:

```
Not in scope: type constructor or class ‘Node’
A data constructor of that name is in scope; did you mean DataKinds?
```

Why is that? How can I define a function which accepts (and compares) Nodes and Trees of arbitrary types?

Comment: A `Node` isn't a type, it's a value. You want `member :: BinaryTree a -> BinaryTree a -> Bool`.

Comment: I think that should be  `member :: a -> BinaryTree a -> Bool`

Comment: @user3585010 Er, yeah, looks like you're right.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`Node` isn't a type; it's a:

- value of type `BinaryTree` when fully applied
- a data constructor for such a value (`a -> BinaryTree a -> BinaryTree a -> BinaryTree a`)

*Both really mean the same, but it can be helpful to realize the appearance in two different contexts, namely pattern matching and construction.*

Your `member` function most probably should take just the element to check for its existence:

```
member :: a -> BinaryTree a -> Bool
```

If you need additional constraints on the `a` (in the case of a binary tree, it's going to be `Ord` and `Eq`, most probably, you have to put them there too.

```
member :: (Ord a, Eq a) => a -> BinaryTree a -> Bool
```

Comment: No instance for (Eq a) arising from a use of ‘==’ etc.

Based on your answer and with a bit of googling:

member :: (Ord a) => a -> BinaryTree a -> Bool
if you update your response to reflect that I'll accept it
thanks!

Comment: @AbrahamP those appear because of the implementation of `member`, but yeah, you have to add them.

Comment: I'm fairly new to haskell, but I think your first bullet point is slightly wrong. `Node` isn't a value of type `BinaryTree`, it is of type `a -> BinaryTree a -> BinaryTree a -> BinaryTree a`.

Comment: @CameronMartin Added a note to avoid further confusion.

Comment: `Ord` is a subclass of `Eq`, you don't need to specify the latter.